# How to remove default html tag attribute in IE7

Tags: html

I have following html code,

```
<tr>
  <td>abc</td>
  <td>xyz</td>
</tr>
```

while run this above code in IE7, automatically adding default attributes, eg: `disabled="disabled"`, how to remove default attribute from IE7

```
<tr id="" onblur="null" disabled="disabled" ......>
   <td>abc</td>
   <td>xyz</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Who/what is adding this "default attributes"? The CMS? The Browser itself? I have never seen such default values o.0

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you can do that on the fly after the completation of the document.

$("tr").removeAttr("disabled")